# Should the URL path of my classifieds site include the city for the offer?

Tags: seo, url, local-seo

My classified ads site has cities.  Should the URL of the offered item included the city locale? For example:

```
/city-name/category-name/sub-category-name/abcd.html
```

Comment: You tagged this as "SEO", but the words used in the URL path have very little ranking impact right now.

Comment: As @StephenOstermiller stated, this is actualy even officially stated by Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a few factors you should consider in that case.

1. Keywords in URLs are overrated and don't really have much impact on page ranking.
2. Best practice always keep URLs as short and simple as possible.
3. It is usually a good practice to omit the categories in URL. Because If you decided to change the name of the category for example, then you would also have to redirect all pages with the category in URL. So I always prefer /product before /category/product since its more robust.

Comment: But do you prefer to add city to the url for example if the people want to look at electronic devices in Los Angeles the url should be: /los-angeles/electronic-device or /electronic-device/los-angeles?

Comment: You don't have to keep the city in URL. Communicate the city in the content (H1, title etc.) @NguyenTuPham

Comment: Thanks, but should I keep the category-name in the url?